# what is the difference between raisepropertychanged and PropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, mvvm

i think both are same,but i found use of them in only one file such as below code.here code for raisepropertychanged  .

```
public decimal Amount
        {
            get
            {
                return _amount;
            }
            set
            {
                _amount = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Amount");
            }
        }
```

here code for PropertyChanged:

```
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        // take a copy to prevent thread issues
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

plz explain difference between them:

Comment: I didnt understand the code.. could you explain more.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`PropertyChanged` is an event. `RaisePropertyChanged` is the method used to raise the event.

Of course, you could invoke the event directly from your property setter, but then you would have to check every time if the handler is not null... better to do it in one place.

Comment: The event exists in `Entity`. There really is no difference. He could have the event and the invoking method in his own class, or he could have it in his base class. Both the event and the method still exist. `Entity` simply wraps the event handling with `RaisePropertyChanged`

Comment: There's no difference between what? Between an event and a method? Of course there is! And again, the OP never said anything about `Entity`...

Comment: Of course there's a difference between an event and a method, but this isn't the case. The event is there either way, and the method is there as well. The question is about the difference between USING `RaisePropertyChanged` and the regular PropertyChanged event.

Comment: And again, the OP doesn't have to say the exact word. `RaisePropertyChanged` is a method that belongs to the class `Entity`, and he also tagged his question with the `MVVM` tag. That says it all.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque :after raising **RaisePropertyChanged("Amount");** i have seen that at debug time (using f-10 key) next line executed was get{ return _amount;}why this happen .any idea about it?

Comment: why code goes into get method at debug time after executing  RaisePropertyChanged("Amount")? why this happen?

Comment: @prjndhi, because raising the PropertyChanged event refreshes the binding, so the property value is read again.

Comment: IMHO, SimpleVar's comments are off-purpose here. As this answer indicates, it is a convenience for setters to call `RaisePropertyChanged` - if they didn't, each setter would instead have to duplicate the code found in `RaisePropertyChanged`. This is true, regardless of whether one is using an MVVM library that already contains a `RaisePropertyChanged` method, or rolling one's own.